# Function getElementsByClassName() shows error in console

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, console

My code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/game.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<meta charset="UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body onload="generate()">
<table border="1">
<tr class="1">
</tr>
</table>
<script>
function generate()
{
        var gen = document.getElementsByClassName("1");
        for (var j=1;j<=10;j++)
        {
            var gens = document.createElement("td");
            var gens2 = document.getElementsByClassName("1").appendChild(gens);
            gens.setAttribute("class", 1.j);
        }
}
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

WHen I open it with browser it shows in consol: var gens2 = document.getElementsByClassName("1").appendChild(gens);
this line has error.

Comment: What is the i in the getElementsByClassName parameters ?

Comment: I removed some code, and there was "for" loop with var i

Answer (score 1):

what your looking for is:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("1")[0];
```

Why your doesnt work is because its getting all the elements with the class name of one. You haven't specified which element to get the data from.

Answer (score 1):

The document.getElementsByClassName() function return an array of elements (look at the "s" on elements. To access the first returned element use this:

```
document.getElementsByClassName("1")[0];
```

If you don't now how many elements are returned, just loop on the length of the returned array.